# CSS background-position not applying to my class

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

Here is my CSS:

```
.header
{
    background-image:url(Images/head.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:1010px;
    height:269px;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>xSky Software - Most likely the only software on Clickbank that exists.</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="header"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get my image centered on the X-axis, and top'ed on the Y-axis. However my CSS class `.header` wont do that. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Turning the top center around does not work either

Comment: So the `.header` image is displaying, just not staying centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `background-position` is `left top`. Try flipping the values.

You'll also need `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/rjSP9/).

Comment: It has to be centered - the above there does what I already have. :P

Comment: @Jeff See fiddle now. Is that what you are after?

Comment: See my edit, applied your changes, but they dont apply on my page

Comment: @Jeff You may be implementing it incorrectly, as you can see it does work on the fiddle. Any way I can see where it's been implemented? I'm sure I can then see what is going on :)

Comment: @Alex - Its just locally - by applying the border, I saw that it was indeed centered, but its my DIV tag that needs to be centered aswell - how do I do that?

Comment: @Jeff You don't use `background-position` to position the element itself. :P

Comment: @Alex - I got it, setting the Margin-Left and Right to Auto! :D

Comment: @Alex - Yeah, I figured. New to this. :P

Comment: @Jeff Yes, that is often the best way to do it with block level elements :)

Comment: @Alex - Trying to create a Logo class, but it wont show. Maybe I should post a new question. It looks bad on me, I got over 40 questions already. :P

Answer (score 2):

Your `background-position` values are around the wrong way. It should be:

```
background-position: 50% 0; /* Short values FTW! */
```

Don't forget if you want it to stay centered, you'll also need to do something like wrap the content in a container and use `margin:0 auto` on it to keep everything centered.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
    width:1010px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header {
    width:1010px;
    height:265px;
    background:transparent url('//placehold.it/1010x265') no-repeat;
}
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/UGDxU/show](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/UGDxU/show)** (or [edit it](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/UGDxU/))